# How to set the default font used in the MT4 Comment() function?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mt4

The default font used for the *`Comment("some text")`* function is not not a *fixed-width* (aka *monotype*) and it is often too small.

**How can I change the default font used for `Comment()`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Q** : *How can I change the default font used for **`Comment()`**?*

Having used **`MQL4`** since 2007+ there is, so far, **no way to change a font** used for `Comment()` (or the graph Time-/Price-axes).

---

[image]

As [@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5069609/daniel-kniaz) has remarked, there are some chances to build tools to circumvent this trouble.

[image]
I have used a similarly motivated **`Comment()`**-based approach for a text-editor, for a `(row,col)`-addressable text-screen ( still inside a `Comment()`-text-block ), for an independent overlay with a `(row,col,font,color)`-text-screen and last, but not least, years ago I started to use a distributed-computing approach, so as not to remain blocked with the absence of screen-controls for the text-part of the GUI ( having a freedom of using several independent graphical views ( multi-time-frame views, views with AI/ML-analytical post-processing graphing and many others ).

Using the Terminal-GUI for a default look-and-feel is accompanied with any number of "remote"-screens ( implemented in python and other, non-MQL4, domain languages, some HPC-languages on remote computers ) that are used in-sync with the flow of `MQL4`-processed events.

This is the safest way to work with text-and-graphs in a user-controlled manner.

Comment: `... for an independent overlay with a (row,col,font,color)-text-screen.` Sound nice, and would have been interesting to see how it works. The main problem with the *Comment()* is that it is using a variable width font so it's impossible to align text and numbers in columns, without ugly [beep] hacks. Since you mentioned the topic of the *distributed computing approach*, perhaps you could point to some useful resources how to start using that (integrating with MT4/5)?

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my belief, there is no way to change font type and size of the `Comment()` function. If they are too small for you - you have to draw Labels on the chart yourself(even though it might be a bit inconvenient to parse the text looking for "`\n`" objects in order to go next line).

Comment: Yes, I already draw and print stuff to the chart, but was hoping to find some windows app setting that would change the font, as it seemed that most other fonts and sizes are available.

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy to change the default font for everything (not just comments) you can modify

```
#define CONTROLS_FONT_NAME                  "Tahoma"
#define CONTROLS_FONT_SIZE                  (8)//changed from 12
```

in the **defines.mqh** file.

Comment: Cool, if it is indeed working, not only for { TimeDOMAIN, PriceDOMAIN }-axes, but also for Comment()-driven part of the GUI and/or other flying-cursor texts. ***A fair note*** is, that this feature **was not present in MQL4 language for many years, almost for ages** *and that it has first appeared in Build X.YZUV until 2020....* Would you add that to the answer, so as to make it fair & complete?